# How can I know the bus speed of my laptop's motherboard?

Tags: motherboard

I want to know the bus speed of my mainboard , so that I can be sure about the   bus speed of my RAM .

My laptop is : asus k42f

Note: I am asking for tools or software or any trick which will tell me the exact and details info about my motherboard .

Comment: Check the manual.

Comment: Oh common. It took me 30 seconds to find out what ram your laptop supports including the bus speed. Just search google for "asus k42f ram".

Comment: It is my fault that I couldn't ask the question so that people understand . anyway I am asking for a tool or technique to find the supported bus speed of any motherboard

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cnet.com/products/asus-k42f-a1-14-core-i3-350m-windows-7-home-premium-64-bit-4-gb-ram-320-gb-hdd/specs/
took me like 5sec lol. u could needed spend less time googeling it that asking here :D

Comment: Anybody can google  , but I failed to say what I actually meant .  It is not my laptop , I bought mine 5 years earlier . My laptop comes with core i5 2.40 with only 2 GB ram , later I have upgraded to it 4 GB . Today's asus k42f is not similar to the which I have bought .  Anyway I am planning to upgrade RAM one more time , hence I need to know the highest supported bus speed of the main board . So that I can buy ram of similar bus speed .